# Adwords Tracking Template URL requires Google Analytics vals?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

When setting up an Adwords Tracking Template URL, do I need to include parameters that Google Analytics uses to track Adwords clicks? Or does google handle adding those? For example, if my tracking template url looks like this:

https://domain.com/admin/tracking-template?destination={lpurl}

Do I need to add ValueTrack or other parameters for Google Analytics to properly track the click after I forward it to the proper landing page? If so, is there any documentation as to what these parameters are named?

I understand that my forwarding script will have to make use of them if present, I just don't know what they are and if they are automatically passed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "parameters that Google Analytics uses to track Adwords clicks" you're referring to the GCLID, then as long as you have "auto-tagging" enabled, the GCLID will be automatically happened at the end of the ad URL.

As you said, you need to make sure your redirect platform properly pass it along.